# Print a webpage without any prompt? using javascript or jquery or vbscript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I want to print a webpage that resides inside my website using javascript or jquery or vbscript or any client side scripting language that can run on IE, without any prompt.

for example function should just take in the URL of page and send print command to the printer.

```
window.print(URL);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is impossible.

Allowing web pages to use ink and paper resource without permission would be an insane thing for a browser to do.

Comment: OK what are my options than . The page I want to print the generated by my code.

Comment: Option 1: Let the browser prompt the user. Option 2: Let the user trigger printing manually instead of using JS.

Comment: I can already print the webpage without any prompt using javascript in FF and IE. The only thing that I dont want is to open the page first and than print it.

Comment: append a hidden iframe to the page that contains the URL, then print that iframe with javascript.

Comment: zahid, can you show the code that without prompt print