# POS: get a website to print directly to a defined local printer/s

Tags: php, jquery, printing, local

I have a website which runs a box office service which issues tickets and reports.  I am trying to figure out how to get tickets (currently PDFs) sent directly to a specified printer on a local/client PC.

I have followed many old/dead/useless links and have not found any up-to-date solutions to this although many tantalising glimmers of hope.

The scenario is this: Remote hosted website - 1 or more users connected - web page generates ticket/s (PDF) which is sent to a specified printer on the user pc (not the default printer) silently (no extra clicking through of print prompts).

I know PHP does not connect to a clients pc but is there a way for a web page (via jQuery perhaps) to connect to an installed script/service?

I was thinking the script on a local PC (which establishes a trusted link, sets the printer to use, etc) would receive data/file from the web server and then process it as long as it was in the same place on every machine.  This (local) script then can be added to any PC that needs to run the service.  The work would need to be trigged by the file being sent and not having a script/service which is sat polling a location every few seconds.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I have tried the jZebra java applet but only got it printing once before it broke. Interested if anyone has actually got it to work (and how).

Comment: No, not really possible. jquery is restricted by the same-origin security policy. Unless your printers have a JSONP printing interface, there's no practical way for you to tell the browser to automatically print to that printer without user intervention - consider that if it were possible, spammers would be burning through your paper supply to tell you about russian brides who want to sell you boner pills supplied by dead nigerian goverment officials.

Comment: The intention/thought is to use something like jQuery to pass a file to a script/software running on a local machine which then in turn would send it to a printer.  Having the script installed locally provides the level of security to accept the incoming file and then process it.

Comment: js cannot execute local programs. and js loaded from a remote webserver wouldn't be able to load any "local" code or invoke it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically Print Image from Website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945691/automatically-print-image-from-website)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print a webpage without any prompt? using javascript or jquery or vbscript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004085/print-a-webpage-without-any-prompt-using-javascript-or-jquery-or-vbscript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print directly to label printer from Internet Explorer without prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992798/how-to-print-directly-to-label-printer-from-internet-explorer-without-prompt)

Comment: possible duplicate of [print html table without a prompt a preview window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11610426/print-html-table-without-a-prompt-a-preview-window)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate: the question states that I need to be able to select to which printer on a particular pc to print to - and is looking at piping a file to another script/software resident on a clients pc.

Answer (score 14):

I ran into the EXACT same question recently myself. Google Chrome has what's called a "kiosk" mode. Therefore, it will print without user intervention.

To do this, open Google Chrome with the following command (you need to find the chrome executable, or chrome command for *nix machines):

```
chrome.exe "http://www.example.com/mypage.php" --kiosk --kiosk-printing
```

This will open a window without any toolbars, address bars, omniboxes, etc.

Next, you need to make a page print. To do this, automatically open a print dialog (for demonstration, I'll use simple Javascript):

```
<script>
  window.print();
</script>
```

Before you jump over to your development environment, `window.print()` does **NOT** allow any arguments (i.e. a URL).

This code opens a print dialog. However, in kiosk mode, the print dialog will be bypassed, and the page will be automatically printed to the default printer.

Now you mentioned a PDF, and chances are, your generating it via PHP (if you are printing issued/generated files), your probably thinking "oh, well I can't put HTML in the PDF to execute the javascript". **You don't need to!** To solve the issue of printing the correct page, here's how:

Insert the following into an HTML/PHP page that the user is sent to (for this solution, the user **does not need to visit the .pdf**), in the `<head>` of the landing/success page:

```
<link rel="alternate" media="print" href="LINK TO PDF FILE">
```

If you have the above code in your page, when you execute `window.print();`, it will print the page specified above. If you don't save the PDF locally, you can put it in a temporary directory that is somehow (out of the scope of this question) cleared on a time based or action based schedule, to prevent disk space buildup.

**Keep the following in mind:**

- Kiosk mode doesn't have an exit button. To exit, press `ALT + F4`.
- When printing in kiosk mode, you need both `--kiosk` **AND** `--kiosk-printing`. The printing argument **requires** the `--kiosk` argument.
- When printing in kiosk mode, it is **normal** for the print dialog to appear and then suddenly disappear. It can't be prevented without advanced window layering and whatnot.

I'm sure that other browsers have similar functionality to bypass the print dialog, however, I have found that Google Chrome works best in this kind of functionality. If your on a Linux machine, Google has a .deb file that you can install Google Chrome on Linux with, by using the command `sudo dpkg -i (package / downloaded .deb file path)`. Chromium --might-- support this kind of functionality. As far as I know, it should.

If you need additional help, leave your question in the comments below, I'll respond ASAP.

I hope I helped. If I did, feel free to give me a green check to your left. ;)

Comment: Not going to lie this is one of the most informative answers on SO I have ever seen. I have never even heard of kiosk mode.

Comment: @Pitchinnate Thank you for the compliment. I try to help people whenever I can, regardless of how informative the answers are. There's no such thing as a stupid question. Once again, thank you for the constructive feedback. :)

Comment: Thank you for a very informative and interesting answer, I never knew Chrome had this function! :o)  Unfortunately for me there I have two issues 1)as windows.print does not accept any arguments it can't be set to print to a particular printer (in my case a ticket printer). 2) I often have the browser resized to be able to read emails for orders at the same time.  Thank you though for the insight into Kiosk mode!

Comment: @lxsparks Thanks for the constructive feedback! I also included in the answer above a way to choose the page to be printed. By the way, if my answer solved your question, click the green checkmark to the left of it. It will award me reputation (which I need, so I can eventually post comments to get more information such as versions, etc), and it will mark it as the answer that was correct, or provided the most information. Thanks! :)

Comment: @NetworkNerd Nice solution.  I run a similar app as the OP and instead of opening additional pages, I load a pdf in an iframe and call the print function from kiosk mode for that iframe instead.  I have run into the problem where sometimes it prints a blank label/receipt as the pdf has not loaded by the time the command to print goes through.  As a stop-gap, I've used setTimeout to wait an arbitrary amount of time, but I'd like to be able to know definitively when the pdf is available to print.  Does your solution with a <link> tag solve this issue?

Comment: @AustinK i am almost sure your answer is part of my solution, but in my case I have just an one page project (a ticket scanner, which checks barcode, returns pdf + qrcode+name+company). I have got the scan and create pdf part going, but I am not sure where I should put `<script>
  window.print();
</script>` and `<link rel="alternate" media="print" href="LINK TO PDF FILE">`. Because, onload the pdf is not yet created, only after the scan and the user returns (with ajax) the pdf is created.

Comment: btw in theory the following should print test.pdf, correct? in my case it doesn't `<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="alternate" media="print" href="http://localhost/mydomain.com/test/test.pdf">
        <script>
            window.print();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: @alex Try moving the `<script>window.print();</script>` piece to outside the `<head>` element. Also - what browser are you using to test it?