# How to print another file than the current one?

Tags: javascript, html, printing, window

I thought this simple setup would work and use the alternate link to print test.pdf. But in the print preview I see the current page and not test.pdf???

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="alternate" media="print" href="http://localhost/mydomain.com/test/test.pdf">
        <script>
            window.print();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[edit] 
the closest I got only seems to work in Chrome (I like to skip the print preview and auto print, but the --kiosk doesn't seem to play along with following code):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                function print(url)
                {
                    var _this = this,
                            iframeId = 'iframeprint',
                            $iframe = $('iframe#iframeprint');
                    $iframe.attr('src', url);

                    $iframe.load(function () {
                        callPrint(iframeId);
                    });
                }

                //initiates print once content has been loaded into iframe
                function callPrint(iframeId) {
                    var PDF = document.getElementById(iframeId);
                    PDF.focus();
                    PDF.contentWindow.print();
                }
                print('http://localhost/mydomain.com/tests/test.pdf');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="">
        <div>TODO write content</div>
        <iframe id="iframeprint" src=""></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: window.print() only looks for current page and prints it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this to a `pdf` file. But you can do this to an `html` file.

Something like this:

```js
function print() {
  var w = window.open('', 'width=400, height=400');
  w.document.body.innerHTML = "HTML";
  w.print();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="print()">Print another file</button>
```

You can see it here: http://output.jsbin.com/kefoxo

**The full code:** (Tested on `Google Chrome`)

http://jsbin.com/kefoxo/edit?html,js

Comment: hmmm, that is not exactly what I am looking for. I need to auto print a generated pdf after a successfull scan. I am just stuck with the auto print part. In your solution can i have the pdf as innerHTML ?? ps1: this will be a standalone/kiosk like setup ps2 i am trying to follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18019219/pos-get-a-website-to-print-directly-to-a-defined-local-printer-s

Comment: I know it's not exactly you want.. `after a successful scan`? What exactly is your final product? a website? an extension?

Comment: I have edit my question with some almost workable code.  As my final product, in short I am developing a ticket scanner. User registers online -> brings ticket -> on event side -> ticket gets scanned -> badge will be printed with qr code. At the moment I don't have the printer (i am told it will be a zebra/evolis printer), but I am testing with creating a pdf badge. It all seems to work except for the printing part. I am seeing the "preview" printing part and also saving the pdf save an A4 (but i guess this has to do with default printer settings). Hope you can give me some more pointers tips?